# Mis-aligned pointers on x86

Tags: c, pointers, alignment, casting

Can someone provide an example were casting a pointer from one type to another fails due to mis-alignment?

In the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544928/reading-integer-size-bytes-from-a-char-array/544964#544964), bothie states that doing something like

```
char * foo = ...;
int bar = *(int *)foo;
```

might lead to errors even on x86 if alignment-checking is enabled.

I tried to produce an error condition after setting the alignment-check flag via `set $ps |= (1<<18)` in GDB, but nothing happened.

What does a working (ie non-working ;)) example look like?

---

None of the code snippets from the answers fail on my system - I'll try it with a different compiler version and on a different pc later.

Btw, my own test code looked like this (now also using asm to set `AC` flag and unaligned read and write):

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    #ifndef NOASM
    __asm__(
        "pushf\n"
        "orl $(1<<18),(%esp)\n"
        "popf\n"
    );
    #endif

    volatile unsigned char foo[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    volatile unsigned int bar = 0;

    bar = *(int *)(foo + 1);
    assert(bar == 0x05040302);

    bar = *(int *)(foo + 2);
    assert(bar == 0x06050403);

    *(int *)(foo + 1) = 0xf1f2f3f4;
    assert(foo[1] == 0xf4 && foo[2] == 0xf3 && foo[3] == 0xf2 &&
        foo[4] == 0xf1);

    return 0;
}
```

The assertion passes without problems, even though the generated code definitely contains the unaligned access `mov -0x17(%ebp), %edx` and `movl $0xf1f2f3f4,-0x17(%ebp)`.

---

So will setting `AC` trigger a `SIGBUS` or not? I couldn't get it to work on my Intel dual core laptop under Windows XP with none of the GCC versions I tested (MinGW-3.4.5, MinGW-4.3.0, Cygwin-3.4.4), whereas codelogic and Jonathan Leffler mentioned failures on x86...

Comment: That code will crash and burn off x86 systems (SPARC, PPC, possibly IA64 unless that is set to be tolerant).

Comment: It's not the compiler or OS, it's the x86 - it's very tolerant of this error. See Michael Burr's answer

Comment: @Mark: So did the other people imagine errors being raised?

Comment: Christoph, did you examine the disassembly and try stepping through it?

Comment: @codelogic: yes, I have - the unaligned access is definitely there: `mov -0x17(%ebp), %edx`

Comment: Christoph: then I would recommend double checking that the flag was indeed set, by reading it. I updated my answer with another asm snippet.

Comment: @codelogic: reading the flag with your asm snippet will return 0; but I'm not sure if the code isn't broken - when I rewrote it with intel syntax and using some macro magic I had lying around, it returned the correct value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an additional condition, not mentioned, for EFLAGS.AC to actually take effect. CR0.AM must be set to prevent INT 17h from tripping on older OSes predating the 486 that have no handler for this exception. Unfortunately, Windows do not set it by default, you need to write a kernel-mode driver to set it.

Comment: I don't believe a kernel mode driver is required. Perhaps I'm reading the response wrong. See [Windows Data Alignment on IPF, x86, and x64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 21):

The situations are uncommon where unaligned access will cause problems on an x86 (beyond having the memory access take longer).  Here are some of the ones I've heard about:

1. You might not count this as x86 issue, but SSE operations benefit from alignment.  Aligned data can be used as a memory source operand to save instructions.  Unaligned-load instructions like `movups` are slower than `movaps` on microarchitectures before Nehalem, but on Nehalem and later (and AMD Bulldozer-family), unaligned 16-byte loads/stores are about as efficient as unaligned 8-byte loads/stores; single uop and no penalty at all if the data happens to be aligned at runtime or doesn't cross a cache-line boundary, otherwise efficient hardware support for cache-line splits.  4k splits are very expensive (~100 cycles) until Skylake (down to ~10 cycles like a cache line split).  See https://agner.org/optimize/ and performance links in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for more info.
2. interlocked operations (like `lock add [mem], eax`) are *very* slow if they aren't sufficiently aligned, especially if they cross a cache-line boundary so they can't just use a cache-lock inside the CPU core.  On older (buggy) SMP systems, they *might* actually fail to be atomic (see https://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/30/222631.aspx).
3. and another possibility discussed by Raymond Chen is when dealing with devices that have hardware banked memory (admittedly an oddball situation) - https://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/27/221486.aspx
4. I recall (but don't have a reference for - so I'm not sure about this one) similar problems with unaligned accesses that straddle page boundaries that also involve a page fault.  I'll see if I can dig up a reference for this.

And I learned something new when looking into this question (I was wondering about the "`$ps |= (1<<18)`" GDB command that was mentioned in a couple places).  I didn't realize that x86 CPUs (starting with the 486 it seems) have the ability to cause an exception when a misaligned access is performed.

From Jeffery Richter's "Programming Applications for Windows, 4th Ed":

> Let's take a closer look at how the x86 CPU handles data alignment. The x86 CPU contains a special bit flag in its EFLAGS register called the AC (alignment check) flag. By default, this flag is set to zero when the CPU first receives power. When this flag is zero, the CPU automatically does whatever it has to in order to successfully access misaligned data values. However, if this flag is set to 1, the CPU issues an INT 17H interrupt whenever there is an attempt to access misaligned data. The x86 version of Windows 2000 and Windows 98 never alters this CPU flag bit. Therefore, you will never see a data misalignment exception occur in an application when it is running on an x86 processor.

This was news to me.

Of course the big problem with misaligned accesses is that when you eventually go to compile the code for a non-x86/x64 processor you end up having to track down and fix a whole bunch of stuff, since virtually all other 32-bit or larger processors are sensitive to alignment issues.

Comment: "SSE operations must deal with aligned data" is not necessarily true anymore. On recent Intel CPUs (Penryn and newer, I think), the "aligned" and "unaligned" SSE ops actually do the same thing, which happens to be a bit slower if the access is unaligned.

Comment: Yeah, on pre-Penryn CPUs unaligned SSE reads will kill performance. Supposedly on Penryn, though (I don't have one to benchmark), the CPU will just do two aligned reads and use the Penryn "Super Shuffle Engine" to piece them back together into the requested unaligned read, so they're not so slow.

Comment: I just benched it -- Penryn unaligned SSE ops still have about three times the latency of an aligned read, although their throughput is better than it was in previous cores. This is consistent with the behavior you describe (and with the way that VMX handles it, eg load load shuffle).

Comment: Just curious - ant idea what the hit was pre-Penryn? A wild-ass-guess is fine by me, since I'm just curious.

Comment: Minor correction to "interlocked operations must operate on aligned data to ensure they are atomic on multiprocessor systems".  Interlocked operations will work on unaligned data on X86, they just happen to have edge cases that are *MUCH* slower but your code shouldn't crash.  FWIW, you don't have to use full alignment for interlocked operations on some PowerPC's as well (for example a certain game system made by Microsoft will handle 64-bit interlocks that are only 32-bit aligned just fine).

Comment: @Adisak - thanks for the clarification on that point.  Definitely an area where if you're depending on that behavior, you'd better know what's what.

Comment: @kquinn: it's Nehalem where `movqdu` became fast: always single uop, and same perf as `movdqa` if used on aligned data.  With the "super shuffle engine" stuff, perhaps you were thinking of using SSSE3 `palignr` for src and dst misaligned relative to each other?  Penryn's 128-bit shuffle unit made it single uop, vs. 2 on Conroe/Merom.  https://agner.org/optimize/.  So it can speed up algorithms that use that strategy + `movdqa`, but not `movdqu` itself.

Answer (score 8):

If you read up on the Core I7 architecture (specifically, their optimization literature), Intel has actually put a TON of hardware in there to make misaligned memory accesses nearly free. As far as I can tell, only a misalignment that crosses a cache line boundary has any extra cost at all - and even then it is minimal. AMD also has very little trouble with misaligned accesses (cycle-wise) as far as I remember (it's been a while though).

For what it's worth, I did set that flag in eflags (the AC bit - alignment check) when I was getting carried away optimizing a project that I was working on. It turns out that windows is FULL of misaligned accesses - so many that I wasn't able to locate any misaligned memory accesses in our code, I was bombarded with so many misaligned accesses in libraries and windows code that I didn't have time to continue.

Perhaps we can learn that when CPUs make things free or very low cost, programmers WILL become complacent and do things that have a little extra overhead. Perhaps Intel's engineers did some of that investigation, and found that typical x86 desktop software does millions of misaligned accesses per second, so they put incredibly fast misaligned access hardware in CoreI7.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

char *foo is probably aligned to int boundaries.
Try this:

```
int bar = *(int *)(foo + 1);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did - did you check this? What happens that is not supposed to happen?

Answer (score 2):

```
char *foo = "....";
foo++;
int *bar = (int *)foo;
```

The compiler would put foo on a word boundary, and then when you increment it it's at a word+1, which is invalid for a int pointer.

Comment: It appears that Core2Duo in 64 bit mode doesn't produce this error.

Comment: On x86 it's prefectly valid to access misaligned data as long as you've not set the flag to give an exception on unaligned data. It's just potentially slower.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char c[] = "a";

  printf("%d\n", *(int*)(c));
}
```

This gives me a [SIGBUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGBUS) after setting `set $ps |= (1<<18)` in gdb, which apparently is thrown when address alignment is incorrect (amongst other reasons).

EDIT: It's fairly easy to raise SIGBUS:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* EDIT: enable AC check */
    asm("pushf; "
        "orl $(1<<18), (%esp); "
        "popf;");

    char c[] = "1234567";
    char d[] = "12345678";
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at main's disassembly in gdb:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
....
0x08048406 <main+34>:   mov    0x8048510,%eax
0x0804840b <main+39>:   mov    0x8048514,%edx
0x08048411 <main+45>:   mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
0x08048414 <main+48>:   mov    %edx,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048417 <main+51>:   movl   $0x34333231,-0x19(%ebp)   <== BAM! SIGBUS
0x0804841e <main+58>:   movl   $0x38373635,-0x15(%ebp)
0x08048425 <main+65>:   movb   $0x0,-0x11(%ebp)
```

Anyhow, Christoph your test program fails under Linux raising a SIGBUS as it should. It's probably a Windows thing?

---

You can enable the Alignment Check bit in code using this snippet:

```
/* enable AC check */
asm("pushf; "
    "orl $(1<<18), (%esp); "
    "popf;");
```

Also, ensure that the flag was indeed set:

```
unsigned int flags;
asm("pushf; "
    "movl (%%esp), %0; "
    "popf; " : "=r"(flags));
fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", flags & (1<<18));
```

Comment: I fail to reproduce this with gcc (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3), I'll try later with a different version...

Comment: This was compiled with gcc 4.3.2 running kernel 2.6.27 on an Intel Core 2 Duo.

Comment: Also, it doesn't throw a SIGBUS without setting the flag you mentioned.

Comment: The reason it might be failing is that it's attempting to dereference an int from 2 byte char[], although like I said, it doesn't happen when the flag isn't set.

Comment: perhaps it's a weird windows thing - neither gcc3.4.5 nor gcc4.3.0 produces failing code for me...

Comment: also, I wanted the code to fail due to misalignment, so you should provide enough chars to not fail because of illegal data access...

Comment: I have no idea why you think that "fairly easy SIGBUS" program would cause a SIGBUS.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Paul, it'll only raise SIGBUS if you set the AC flag like Christoph mentioned in the question, while debugging in gdb.

Comment: but the program is totally valid. it's a bug in something else then. you don't read unaligned data there

Comment: @litb: Yes, the program is valid. However the instruction "movl   $0x34333231,-0x19(%ebp)" is performing an assignment of the value 0x34333231 to the address starting at (%ebp - 0x19), which in this case is not aligned, hence the exception.

Comment: Added an ASM snippet that should enable alignment check without requiring gdb.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a bug in your code reading the flag?

Comment: In old architectures (SPARC, Vax) cast of an unaligned char to int would produce an immediate core dump.  But those compilers would align a char[] to a word boundary.  It looks like gcc on Intel doesn't any more, possibly because it doesn't normally cause a core dump.

Comment: @Christoph: not sure, but it seems to be doing the right thing. Prints '262144' only if AC is enabled, otherwise prints 0.

Comment: @codelogic: there's a pair of parentheses missing - it should read `movl (%%esp), %0`

Comment: Oops, my test program was already using (%%esp), which is why I was getting expected results. I must have fixed it after updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To enjoy the exception, call `SetErrorMode` with `SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   SetErrorMode(GetErrorMode() | SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT);
   ...
}
```

See [Windows Data Alignment on IPF, x86, and x64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

gcc when auto-vectorizing assumes that `uint16_t*` is aligned to a 2-byte boundary.  If you violate this assumption, you can get a segfault: 
 [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64)

So respecting C alignment rules matters even when targeting x86.

---

Use this to efficiently express an unaligned load in C:

```
static inline
uint32_t load32(char *p)     // char*  is allowed to alias anything
    uint32_t tmp;
    memcpy(&tmp, p, sizeof(tmp));
    return tmp;
}
```

On x86 it will compile to the single `mov` you expect (or auto-vectorize or whatever), but on SPARC or MIPS before MIPS64r6 or whatever it will compile to whatever instruction sequence is necessary for an unaligned load.  This use of `memcpy` will optimize away entirely on targets that support unaligned loads.

i.e. your compiler knows whether the target ISA supports unaligned loads or not, and will emit asm that does them or not as it sees fit.

Comment: [here's a case](https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2020/04/06/gcc-always-assumes-aligned-pointers/) where you don't even need vectorization for misaligned pointers to fail. Very interesting. I don't know if there is a canonical question for this issue (the issue that people assume misalignment is OK when writing C/C++ for x86 since unaligned is mostly allowed there), so I left this here.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: thanks, updated [Why does unaligned access to mmap'ed memory sometimes segfault on AMD64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47510783) with those blog links.  That's the canonical I always link when it comes up, including in this answer.