# What is causing Caffe to throw a Bus error

Tags: machine-learning, caffe, bus-error

For an experiment I have been running, Caffe has been crashing.  My experiment involves training networks on different subsets of the same data using the AlexNet model.  For each trial, I generate an LMDB for that particular subset of data and then modify my network .prototxt to match the parameters.  For 40+ trials, I have had no issue.  One particular trial, however, consistently crashes after 227 training iterations.  The error given is simply "Bus error (core dumped)".  This happens regardless of whether I do the training on GPU or CPU.  Searching has yielded no results of anyone else who has had this error.  Apparently it is some sort of memory addressing error.  I am using an Nvidia DIGITS box with 64GB RAM and and 12GB of VRAM.  The system monitor shows that I am using nowhere near the system's full memory.  I can provide my prototxt if it might be helpful.  However, the dataset is too large too upload (>20GB).

I1128 12:50:01.558748 20000 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 227, loss = 5.8273
I1128 12:50:01.558786 20000 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 5.8273 (* 1 = 5.8273 loss)
I1128 12:50:01.558796 20000 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 227, lr = 0.001
Bus error (core dumped)

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069450/how-to-get-a-bus-error), bus errors are nonexistant on modern Intel machines, which I am using.  What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Please share the core dump. That is the right place to start.

Comment: @prabindh What I posted is the entirety of the log.  Unless the core is dumped to a system log file, I don't have anything else.

Comment: Usually, in Linux it will be a large file called "core" in the same directory as where you are running from. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965/how-to-generate-a-core-dump-in-linux-when-a-process-gets-a-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the cause.  I was using a different computer to generate the LMDB and transferring it to the machine that runs caffe with a flash drive.  For some reason, transferring files to this flash drive lead to the lmdb being truncated from ~20GB to 15GB with no warning to me.  I think that caffe seems to have crashed when it reached the unexpected end of the lmdb.  Retransferring the file and ensuring that it wasn't truncated solved the problem.