# Why does x86 allows for unaligned accesses, and how unaligned accesses can be detected?

Tags: security, memory, x86, cpu-architecture, memory-alignment

Perhaps I misunderstand something, but it seems unaligned access in x86 gives security troubles such as a [*Return Address Integrity*  issue](https://par.nsf.gov/servlets/purl/10197264).

- Why do x86 designers allow for unaligned accesses in the first place? (Performance is the only benefit I can think of.)
- If x86 designers permit this unaligned access trouble, they should somehow know how to solve it, don't they?  Can unaligned accesses get detected with static techniques or sanitization techniques?

Comment: _security troubles such as return address integration issue._ -- could you please elaborate or give a link?

Comment: Many other ISAs support unaligned access now, too.  (But unlikely x86, the implementation often has a performance penalty even when it's within a single cache line).  e.g. AArch64, some ARM, [MIPS32r6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64) (but earlier MIPS revisions didn't guarantee that).

Comment: Note the legality of unaligned access goes all the way back to the 16-bit 8086, where there was nothing larger than 2 bytes anyway.  My guess is that if they thought about it at all, one motivation for allowing this would have been to make it convenient for assembly programmers to use packed data structures.

Comment: The primary designer of x86 was Stephen Morse (who wrote a book about it, it's now [free on his web site](https://www.stevemorse.org/8086/index.html)).  The design choice was made in the late 1970s.  (And couldn't be changed without breaking backwards compat, which is the main thing x86 has going for it.)  Modern static analysis tools probably weren't even dreamed of yet, since most 8080 code was hand-written in asm.  (8086 was designed for easy asm source-porting from 8080).  Also, the Internet barely existed and almost certainly wasn't a consideration, and 8086 had no memory protection.

Comment: On the flip side, are you aware of the [Alignment Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919269/how-to-enable-alignment-exceptions-for-my-process-on-x64) feature on the 486 and higher, which indeed causes a trap on unaligned access?  It's rarely used but does exist.  User software can choose to disable it, though.

Comment: `how unaligned accesses can be detected?` just check the lsb(s)

Comment: @PeterCordes that sounds like an answer. Thanks. Please free to put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm skeptical of the entire premise that there's a security downside here; a quick search of your link doesn't find any mention of unaligned access being a problem.

---

Many other ISAs support unaligned access now, too. e.g. AArch64, later ARM [including ARMv6 and ARMv7](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/Application-Level-Architecture/Application-Level-Memory-Model/Alignment-support/Unaligned-data-access-restrictions-in-ARMv7-and-ARMv6), and even [MIPS32r6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64) (but earlier MIPS revisions didn't guarantee that).  Non-x86 implementations [often have a performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217528/are-there-any-modern-cpus-where-a-cached-byte-store-is-actually-slower-than-a-wo) for unaligned load or especially store, even when it's within a single cache line (which has no penalty on modern x86 for cacheable loads/stores).

The primary designer of 8086 was Stephen Morse (who wrote a book about it, The 8086 Primer, which is [now free on his web site](https://www.stevemorse.org/8086/index.html)).

The x86 design choice was made [between 1976 and 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086). (And couldn't be changed in later x86 without breaking backwards compat, which is the main thing x86 has going for it.)  8086 needed to support byte loads and stores, and the hardware required to support unaligned 2-byte words on its 16-bit bus was presumably minor.  Especially since 8088 was also planned, with an 8-bit bus. I think its only differences from 8086 were in the bus-interface unit.  Or it might have been cheaper to just do it than to implement some mechanism for alignment faults.

There is no obvious security problem, and certainly none that anyone then would have heard of.

[8086 was designed for easy asm source-porting from 8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/the-start-of-x86-intel-8080-vs-intel-8086) - IDK if 8080 could ever load or store 2 bytes at once, but if it allowed doing so, it probably didn't care about alignment, so 8086 needed to support. Modern static analysis tools probably weren't even dreamed of yet, and most 8080 code was hand-written in asm. (Like much early 8086 code, I'd guess.)

The Internet barely existed at the time and almost certainly wasn't a consideration. 8086 had no memory protection or privilege levels, so it certainly wasn't designed with security in mind.  (Unlike contemporary CPUs for minicomputers that ran multi-user OSes).

The only real security threat for PCs at the time AFAIK was boot-sector viruses, and usually those spread by directly executing code that the system auto-ran during boot or from floppies, not attacking vulnerabilities in other programs.  I could imagine malicious data files like .zip or word-processor formats were thought of at some point, but if there is any security advantage to disallowing misaligned accesses, it wasn't anything known then.

Software certainly wasn't spending extra code-size or cycles on hardening, not for decades after 8086.

---

> Can unaligned accesses get detected with static techniques or sanitization techniques?

There's HW support for detecting unaligned accesses on x86, in the form of the AC bit in EFLAGS.  But that's normally unusable because compilers (and hand-written asm memcpy etc. in libc) sometimes use unaligned loads, e.g. to initialize or copy adjacent narrow members of a struct.

GCC has `-fsanitize=alignment` which seems to check for C UB of dereferencing pointers that aren't sufficiently aligned for their type.  e.g. it checks `*int_ptr`, but doesn't add checks for `memcpy(char_arr, &my_int, 4)` even though it inlines as a dword store.  https://godbolt.org/z/ac6K13nc1

Misaligned `lock`ed instructions are extremely expensive (like system-wide bus lock or something), at least when split across two cache lines, and there is special support for detecting them specifically, without complaining about the normal misaligned loads/stores that happen in memcpy for odd sizes.  The mechanisms include a perf counter for it, and a recent addition of an MSR (Model Specific Register) config bit to [let the kernel](https://lwn.net/Articles/790464/) make them [raise an exception](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Split-Locks-Detection).

Cache-line-split `lock`ed instructions *can* apparently be a problem in terms of letting unprivileged code on one core interfere with hard-realtime code on another core.

---

> It seems unaligned access in x86 gives security troubles such as a Return Address Integrity issue.

How so?

The paper you linked mentions alignment *of the Function Lookup Table* in this proposed hardening mechanism.  There are only two instances of the string "align" in the whole paper, and neither of them talk about ARMv7-M's support for unaligned load/store creating any difficulty.  (ARMv7-M is the ISA they're discussing, since it's about hardening embedded systems.)

Comment: Maybe there could be a tool that ptraces a program, enables AC, and then whenever it gets a SIGBUS with si_code=BUS_ADRALN, it would log where it happened, disable AC, swallow the signal, single-step the program, then re-enable AC and resume execution.