# Why it causes an execution error?

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm wondering why does the following code causes an execution error?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    asm("pushf\norl $ 0x40000, (%esp)\npopf\n");
    *((int*) (((char*) malloc(5)) + 1)) = 23;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Q: What did you find when you stepped through it under the debugger?  Q: What is your platform?  Compiler? I'm guessing Linux and GCC, but I don't know... What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: You are setting the alignment-check bit in EFLAGS [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548164/mis-aligned-pointers-on-x86), and writing a 32-bit value to an unaligned address. BTW, 'execution error' is pretty vague. The actual error would be more useful.

Comment: If `sizeof(int)` larger, like 8, then not enough memory allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are modifying alignment check flag, which is AFAIK protected. Or because malloc() returns an aligned region, and your access is unaligned? Not sure, but why do you need to touch this flag at all?