# memory adressing on intel ia 32

Tags: memory, assembly, intel, malware

I know memory addressing can be done with multiples of the word size so for Intel 32 bits, for allocating memory on stack in assembly can be done with

```
    //pseudo code
    sub , esp ,4 // so for allocating for a integer on stack
    sub esp, 8 // for a buffer of size 5 for example b[5]
```

So addressing is done with multiples of 4's. So also referring the locals and parameters on stack is done with

```
     // referring to variable --ebp-4
```

But sometimes in the disassembly I see some instructions like

```
     movb   $0x41, 0xffffffff(%ebp)   ,// refer to ebp-1 for example
```

So it refers to the memory for the 1 bytes.

So it refers to one byte, not multiple of 4 bytes.The multiple of 4 bytes is only for esp? or is it related to every register?

Comment: _"I see some instructions like `ins 0xffffffff, ebp`"_. Could you give a concrete example from an actual disassembly?

Comment: A single byte is not necessarily aligned to 4, it won't be when it is an element of an array or a member of a struct.  That would be wasteful and the processor does not require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The multiple of 4 bytes is only for esp? or is it related to every register?

Note that

`sub esp, N`

doesn't access any memory location, the use is related to *memory alignment* but the instruction itself is a simple *register-immediate* subtraction, **it could use any value.**

For performance reason if you read 16 bits they should be on an address multiple of 2, 32 bits should be on an address multiple of 4.
This is called **natural boundary alignment**.

32 bits systems can only `push`/`pop` 16 or 32 bits values, if we only use multiple of 4 in instructions like `sub esp, N`, the `push`/`pop` access data aligned on their natural boundaries (note that 4 is multiple of 2).

Data on the stack is also accessed directly with instructions like

`mov [ebp-04h], eax`

The principle here is the same, *EBP* is a multiple of 4 (note that its value is the old *ESP* value, before the subtraction) so the 32 bits data is stored in address multiple of 4 (naturally aligned).

The natural alignment of bytes is... 1. Meaning that they should be at address multiple of 1, i.e. everywhere.
That's why `mov [ebp-01h], 'A'` performs as `mov [ebp-04h], 'A'`.

---

<sub>**Trivia**</sub>

<sub>As *rule of thumbs* IA32e **General Purpose** instructions can read/write from bytes to qwords at every address.

The whole alignment story is mostly for performance reasons, unlike RISC machines where they cannot structurally access unaligned data.</sub>

<sub>When initially introduced SSE instructions came with fast "aligned" (like `movaps`) and slow "unaligned" (like `movups`) versions of the same instruction.</sub>

<sub>64 bits systems now explicitly require 128 bits alignment of the stack to better perform with vector instructions (and widened registers).</sub>

<sub>The CPU has a bit in the *EFLAGS* register, the bit *AC*, that let a program enable or disable a strict alignment policy (à la RISC), supposed the OS has enabled this feature (setting *AM* in *CR0*).</sub>

<sub>Aligning data more strictly that the CPU data bus (for whatever definition of it on modern integrated DRAM controller) is pointless.

That's why new ABIs align on 128 bits even the CPU can have 512 bits registers.</sub>

<sub>Alignment requirement for every instruction can be found on the [Manual 2 (the complete set)](http://www.intel.it/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf).</sub>

Comment: A minor addition: There is an SO answer on the EFLAGS.AC bit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/548411/1305969). And according to another excerpt from the "AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume
2: System Programming" [quoted from bytes.com](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/744294-structure-size-directives/2), the EFLAGS.AC flag is only effective in User Mode (CPL=3): _When automatic alignment checking is enabled and CPL=3, a memory reference to an unaligned operand causes an alignment-check exception (#AC)._

Answer (score 0):

For 80x86 (all modes); addressing is always done with byte granularity.

For all normal instructions (excluding extensions like SSE) the CPU doesn't require alignment and any alignment is merely just for performance reasons.