# Using bitwise operators in C++ to change 4 chars to int

Tags: c++, char, int, bit-manipulation

What I must do is open a file in binary mode that contains stored data that is intended to be interpreted as integers.  I have seen other examples such as [Stackoverflow-Reading “integer” size bytes from a char* array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544928/reading-integer-size-bytes-from-a-char-array) but I want to try taking a different approach (I may just be stubborn, or stupid :/). I first created a simple binary file in a hex editor that reads as follows.

`00 00 00 47 00 00 00 17 00 00 00 41`
This (should) equal 71, 23, and 65 if the 12 bytes were divided into 3 integers.

After opening this file in binary mode and reading 4 bytes into an array of chars, how can I use bitwise operations to make char[0] bits be the first 8 bits of an int and so on until the bits of each char are part of the int.

```
 
My integer = 00        00        00        00  
 +           ^         ^         ^         ^
Chars      Char[0]  Char[1]   Char[2]   Char[3]
             00        00        00        47


So my integer(hex) = 00 00 00 47 = numerical value of 71
```

Also, I don't know how the endianness of my system comes into play here, so is there anything that I need to keep in mind?

Here is a code snippet of what I have so far, I just don't know the next steps to take.

```
std::fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Desktop\\hextest.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if(myfile.is_open() == false)
    {
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
    }
    char* mychar;
    std::cout << myfile.is_open() << std::endl;
    mychar = new char[4];
    myfile.read(mychar, 4);
```

I eventually plan on dealing with reading floats from a file and maybe a custom data type eventually, but first I just need to get more familiar with using bitwise operations.
Thanks.

Comment: Stubbornness aside, you could do this by reading an int and using ntohl()

Comment: Your binary file is "big-endian".  So as long as you convert its bytes to integers in a big-endian way, you don't need to worry about the endianness of the computer.

Comment: ...until you move your code to a different system, and try and read data from a big-endian system. Then you'll have problems.

Comment: @Thomi: Hence David's call to `ntohl()` to prevent this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want the bitwise left shift operator:

```
typedef unsigned char u8;  // in case char is signed by default on your platform
unsigned num = ((u8)chars[0] << 24) | ((u8)chars[1] << 16) | ((u8)chars[2] << 8) | (u8)chars[3];
```

What it does is shift the left argument a specified number of bits to the left, adding zeros from the right as stuffing. For example, `2 << 1` is 4, since 2 is `10` in binary and shifting one to the left gives `100`, which is 4.

This can be more written in a more general loop form:

```
unsigned num = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i) {
    num |= (u8)chars[i] << (24 - i * 8);    // += could have also been used
}
```

The endianness of your system doesn't matter here; you know the endianness of the representation in the file, which is constant (and therefore portable), so when you read in the bytes you know what to do with them. The internal representation of the integer in your CPU/memory may be different from that of the file, but the logical bitwise manipulation of it in code is independent of your system's endianness; the least significant bits are always at the right, and the most at the left (in code). That's why shifting is cross-platform -- it operates at the *logical* bit level :-)

Comment: Clean answer. thanks this is help me to resolve my endianess problem

Comment: Does it work correctly with sign? Shouldn't use `unsigned char`?

Comment: @ar2015: You're absolutely right, this code does not work with signed chars since they are implicitly converted to an `int` of the same (numeric) value before the shift is done. I'll add some casts.

Comment: `(24 - i * 8)` requires remembering operator precedence, and assumes particular implementation-defined things. I prefer `((sizeof(unsigned) - i) * CHAR_BITS)` here

Comment: @Caleth: While I agree `CHAR_BITS` is better in library code, for the sake of keeping the example simple I think assuming 8-bit chars is fairly safe; the other types would have to be changed as well lest they have <32 bits. As for operator precedence, surely it's common knowledge that multiplication has higher precedence than subtraction? This is not specific to C++...

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought of using Boost.Spirit to make a binary parser? You might hit a bit of a learning curve when you start, but if you want to expand your program later to read floats and structured types, you'll have an excellent base to start from.

Spirit is very well-documented and is part of Boost. Once you get around to understanding its ins and outs, it's really mind-boggling what you can do with it, so if you have a bit of time to play around with it, I'd really recommend taking a look.

Otherwise, if you want your binary to be "portable" - i.e. you want to be able to read it on a big-endian and a little-endian machine, you'll need some sort of byte-order mark (BOM). That would be the first thing you'd read, after which you can simply read your integers byte by byte. Simplest thing would probably be to read them into a union (if you know the size of the integer you're going to read), like this:

```
union U
{
    unsigned char uc_[4];
    unsigned long ui_;
};
```

read the data into the uc_ member, swap the bytes around if you need to change endianness and read the value from the ui_ member. There's no shifting etc. to be done - except for the swapping if you want to change endianness..

HTH

rlc

Comment: Well I have been using a lot of boost (threads, file system, random, math) so I will probably try to get more familiar with the spirit class.