# Why is extra data being written to my output stream and how can I stop this?

Tags: java, c, sockets

I am trying to build a simple connection between my Java server (it sends information) and my C client (it receives info).

I want to send one single integer representing the size of an array and then a byte array itself. My java code looks like this

```
Socket sc = new Socket("52.187.54.73", 19000);

while(true)
{

System.out.println("Socket open");
DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());

Random rand = new Random(); 
int rlen = rand.nextInt(10)%10 + 1;

 byte[] a = new byte[rlen];
 System.out.println("Size of the array is " + rlen);    


 for(int i = 0; i < rlen; i++)
     a[i] = (byte)rand.nextInt(100);


outToClient.write(rlen);

outToClient.write(a,0,rlen);
//close socket
sc.close(); 
System.out.println("Done!");
//Break once done
break;
}
```

and my C code looks like this

```
 ptr1 = (void *)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
 while(1){ 
      sin_size = sizeof(client_addr);
      connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
      printf("\n Got a connection from (%s ,%d)",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));

   bytes_received = recv(connected,ptr1,10,0);
   if(bytes_received<0){   
  printf("Something went wrong %s\n", strerror(errno));
   } 

   printf("Bytes received: %d \n", bytes_received);
   for(int i =0; i<bytes_received; i++){

    unsigned char a = *(unsigned char *)(ptr1 + i*sizeof(unsigned char));
    printf("Inc: %d", a);

   }
```

Assuming that the above block of code works and I am able to get the value of `rlen` the code for processing the array is as follows:

```
   ptr2 = calloc(rlen, sizeof(unsigned char)); 
   bytes_received = recv(connected, ptr2, 1,0);// incoming, 0);

   printf("bytes received: %d\n", bytes_received);

   for(int i = 0; i < rlen; i++){ 
       printf(" i = %d, val = %d\n ", i,*(unsigned char *)(ptr2 + i*sizeof(unsigned char)));
    }
```

Now the Java server sends a number between 1 and 10. I was earlier trying to read the number sent using `int incoming = *(int *)ptr1;` but for some reason, occasionally I would get huge values like `51020210`.

To check why this was happening and debug I wrote the code block:

```
for(int i =0; i<bytes_received; i++){

    unsigned char a = *(unsigned char *)(ptr1 + i*sizeof(unsigned char));
    printf("Inc: %d", a);

   }
```

It turns out that sometimes, the integer being sent becomes very large.
Why is this happening? On the server side printing out `rlen` shows me the right value, but non-deterministically I get random really large values at the client side.

Note that whatever number I receive on the client side has the first number as the value of `rlen`.

So for example if `rlen` is 6, then the random really large value is something like `689932423`

Later the values of `rlen` will become very large in the order of 1000s so I need to solve this problem and cannot simply take the first byte of whatever I get on the client side.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned char)` is always 1.

Comment: Java's [`DataOutputStream.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(int)) writes a **single byte** to the underlying output stream. You then proceed to read 10 bytes to the buffer pointed to by *ptr1* (which you have not defined in your minimal, complete and verifiable example), after which you cast the pointer to a pointer to int and dereference it. This (probably) breaks aliasing – undefined behaviour – and tries to read too many bytes from your buffer, not to mention possible endianness issues.

Comment: Please indent your code if you expect others to read it.

Comment: @IljaEverilä By "aliasing" you mean "alignment"?

Comment: Could you please replace %d with %hh in the C code and provide an example of the output that you see? It would also be beneficial to see what array processing code do you have in the C part.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Probably _strict aliasing rule_, I guess.

Comment: The C code is so broken, it's hard to decide where to begin explaining what's wrong.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik and @/IljaEverilä I have edited the question with some more details. I will do that and see what the output is. 

(I cannot add more than one user on my comment)

Comment: `ptr1 = (void *)calloc(1, sizeof(int)); ... recv(connected,ptr1,10,0);` You allocate 4 bytes, then allow `recv` to read 10. Just one example.

Comment: Do not [cast the result of malloc and friends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). It serves just to hide possible errors. You still have not shown the declaration of *ptr1*, hence the type is unknown to us. As @MarkoTopolnik pointed out, your code is beyond repair.

Comment: @IvanMushketyk I used %hh instead of %d. 

I used to get something like `Inc: 5`
but now I get `Inc: `

It does not print anything out.

Comment: @IljaEverilä 
From your initial comment, since DataOutputStream is only writing one byte, then I can safely ignore all other bytes so that takes care of one problem.

However, I am just curious to know what is the alternative to getting say an integer or a byte from a void pointer? Or instead of a void pointer can I create a unsigned char pointer instead, and will that work?

Comment: `memcpy` is the safe idiom. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544928/reading-integer-size-bytes-from-a-char-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code was in this line as rightly pointed out in the comments

`bytes_received = recv(connected,ptr1,10,0);`

I was mistakenly trying to read more than 4 bytes which is the exact number needed to convert to an integer value.

Alternatively, to read 4 and only 4 bytes, this could be written as

`bytes_received = recv(connected, ptr1, 4, 0|MSG_WAITALL);`

On the java side, again as pointed out in the comments, the function `write(int)` only sends 1 byte.

To send multiple bytes first the integer must be converted into a 4 byte array, and then each byte in the array must be sent like this

`outToClient.write(rlen_array, 0, 4);`