# It it UB to read some contiguous array cells as a larger type?

Tags: c++, arrays, undefined-behavior

```
char foo[n] = /*init here*/;  // n = 4*k + 4.
int i = 0;
while (i < n) {                            
   int four_bytes = *reinterpret_cast<const int*>(foo + i); // is this UB?
   bar(four_bytes);
   i += 4; 
}
```

In this snippet of code (assuming all data is initted properly, and that the array's length is a multiple of 4), is this `reinterpret_cast` UB?

C++14 and someetimes C++11

Comment: Which version of C++ are you talking about?  It matters for this.

Comment: Should that be `*reinterpret_cast<const int*>`?

Comment: Added C++ version,

Comment: @Brian: yes, thanks for pointing tht out

Comment: Possible duplicate, but missing discussion of UB: [Reading “integer” size bytes from a char* array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544928/reading-integer-size-bytes-from-a-char-array)

Comment: I think this is UB as I can't find any allowed transformation here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alignment**

It is UB when the `char foo[n]` is not sufficiently aligned as an `int` array.

**Size**<sup>1</sup>

When `0 < n < sizeof(int)`, `*reinterpret_cast<const int*>(foo + i);` attempts to refence outside `foo[]`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Did not see "array's length is a multiple of 4" until later.  Yet this still applies on unusual platforms where the sizeof `int` is larger, say 8. (eg. some graphics process of old).  IOWs "array's length is a multiple of 4" is not specified the same as "array's length is a multiple of `sizeof(int)`"

Comment: Can you clarify the alignment part? Specifically, what does "not sufficiently aligned for as an int array" mean?

Comment: (regarding size, it's guaranteed that the array is large enough and that its length is a multiple of the sizeof(int))

Comment: @CuriousLearner Example: An `int` might only be allowed on even addresses and `foo[]` might start on an odd address.

Comment: Ah, I see. To ask a more general question, would the same issue occur if instead of `char`, the array was `int8`, then I tried to read 4 blocks as `int32`?  (or `intx[]` and I wanted to read n blocks as `inty`, where `y = x * n` ?)

Comment: @CuriousLearner No difference, alignment issue applies.

Comment: What would be the right way to do this then? read each element individually?

Comment: The simplest right way is `int bytes; memcpy(&bytes,  foo, sizeof bytes);` (when `n >= sizeof bytes`) and use a good compiler to emit efficient code.  Recall there are endian concerns.  In most cases, the _best_ approach depends on the larger code - something not posted.  Avoid micro-optimization.